# Show that $q=<b_1, b_2, b_3, ...>$ belongs to ${\bf R}^\infty$

Tags: general-topology

> Let $p_1=<a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{13}, ... >$, $p_2=<a_{21}, a_{22}, a_{23}, ...  >$, $\cdots$ be points in ${\bf R}^\infty$, where ${\bf R}^\infty$ being used in the book, is the class of all infinite sequences which are square summable, i.e., the square sum of all the terms in the sequence is finite. Suppose that the sequence of real numbers $<\pi_k(p_n)>=<a_{1k}, a_{2k}, a_{3k}, ... >$ converge to $b_k\in{\bf R}$ for every $k\in{\bf N}$.
>   Show that $q=<b_1, b_2, b_3, ...>$ belongs to ${\bf R}^\infty$.

I have taken this problem from Schaum's Outlines on general topology chapter 8.

---

What I´ve written so far is the fact that $a_{ni}\to b_i$ as $n$ approaches infinity, so for each $i$ we can find an $n_i$ such that 
$$
|b_i|^2<|a_{n_ii}|^2+(\epsilon/2^i).
$$

I claim that $\sum$|a$_{n_ii}$|$^2$ converges, and if I prove this, then we have that $\sum$[|a$_{n_ii}$|$^2$+($\epsilon$/2$^i$)] converges since $\sum$$\epsilon$/2$^i$=$\epsilon$, but I have not had any luck at all proving my claim. The other thing I thought about doing, was to take the diagonal as a sequence, and proving that it belongs to R$^\infty$, but was not lucky with that either.

---

I have thought about this problem for a considerable amount of time, and feel stuck. I will show the question and mention the ideas I've had about this problem, but I would really appreciate the help anybody can give me.

Comment: Of course q is in R^oo.  Is there something about R^oo that you are not telling us like the sequences in R^oo are square summable?

Comment: Well by definition the class of all infinite real sequences <$a_1, a_2, a_3$, ...> which are square summable is denoted by R$^\infty$.

Comment: $R^\infty$ is a good notation to avoid because of ambiguity: sometimes it means all sequences of real numbers; sometimes it means all sequences of real numbers which are eventually zero, meaning that $R^\infty$ is the union of the natural sequence of inclusions $R \subset R^2 \subset R^3 \subset \cdots$. I don't think I've ever seen $R^\infty$ mean all square summable sequences. The usual notation I've seen for the set of square summable sequences is $\ell_2$.

Comment: I believe that what you are talking about is the Hilbert space when applying the ℓ2 metric to the class of infinite sequences which are square summable. In schaum's outlines for general topology page 117, chapter 8, which corresponds to metric and normed spaces you can see the definition which is being used.

Comment: You need an additional hypothesis, that $(p_n)$ is a bounded sequence. Otherwise, let $p_n$ be the point with first $n$ components $1$ and all other components $0$. Then $b_k = 1$ for all $k$, and that sequence isn't square summable.

Comment: Thank you Daniel Fischer. Now I know why I was not going to be able to prove my claim.

Answer (score 2):

This problem as it appears in the book, is not possible to solve, because it is not true. The example which Daniel Fischer gives is perfect, because if we take the sequence p$_n$ as the sequence with the first n terms equal to 1 and the rest equal to 0, then we see that each p$_n$ is clearly square summable, but each b$_n$ is equal to 1 for every n, and therefore b would not belong to R$^{\infty}$.